# How do I install a neon indicator for a light?

Tags: electrical, switch

The switch for the bathroom light is outside the room.

I want to put in a switch with a neon indicator that tells me that the light is on in the room so that users will switch it off.

There are only one blue, one brown and one earth wire at the switch.

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Your switch wiring seems to be a switch loop with no neutral at the switch location. In such situation it is possible to use a neon indicator switch that has a lighted indicator when the switch is OFF provided the light itself is an incandescent bulb. Other types of bulbs may not work correctly with this type of setup.

Your desired setup however is just the opposite. You want the neon indicator to be lighted when the switch is in the ON position. It will not be possible to safely wire up a neon indicator when there is just a switch loop pair at the switch location. In order to get it to work the way you want it will be necessary to run a replacement power cable from the light location to the switch that contains a neutral wire in addition to the two wires for the switch loop. When that replacement cable is in place the neon indicator is wired between the neutral wire and the switched wire that goes to the light fixture.

You would also want to double check that the other wire at the switch is the hot line. If it is not then the light fixture itself is wired up wrong and should be corrected. Proper switch loop wiring feeds the hot wire to the switch and the return back to the light and then the opposite side of the light to the neutral at the light location. This assures that when the light is off there are no live connections inside the light bulb socket.

Comment: Thank you Michael, It is an LED array in the bathroom. I suppose; split the "feed" in the ceiling void using a box, down one cable to ENLin at the fused neon switch (changed to 3amp) then ENLout back up the second cable to the LED in the bathroom. How would one check/recognise "hot line"? Thanks again, Andy